# WPF RichTextBox does not show proper fonts

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I am creating a small tool like text editor. I am fetching fonts from system and applying to text written on editor.

```
string fontName = (string)Fonttype.SelectedItem;

RichTextControl.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(
    System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox.FontFamilyProperty, fontName);
```

But font installed like STMSaradha.ttf(Bengali font) won't show properly on RichTextBox, some text will get combined and don't show properly. Any suggestions?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `some text will get combined and don't show properly` Please include a screenshot of that behaviour.

Comment: screenshot added